# NullPointerException Context errors on code moved from one working source into a Main application

Tags: java, android, android-context

Context is not a strong point of mine, I keep getting this error this is part of code i have moved over from another application and works in there just fine, however i am trying to transplant the code from the smaller app to this main app, as adding it as a library was causing headaches which are best sorted out another day.

So the error i receive is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app, PID: 12564
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:107)
        at com.app.TManager.startUpdatingTrace(TManager.java:229)
        at com.app.activities.ui.routeaction.RouteActionFragment$2.onFinish(RouteActionFragment.java:128)
        at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

So this is the relevant code in TManager:

```
public class TManager extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

    
    BroadcastReceiver sensorReceiver;
    BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    public static Intent locationIntent;
    public static Intent sensorService;
    public LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;

    public static MutableLiveData<Integer> status = new MutableLiveData<Integer>();

    //Empty constructor
    public TManager(){}

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void startUpdating() {

        status.setValue(0);

        //register for sensorBroadcast
        sensorReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                TCIMUEvent tcimuEvent = (TCIMUEvent) intent.getSerializableExtra("imuevent");
                // Log.d(TAG, "In Motion Received "+ tcimuEvent.getTime());
                Runnable provideDM = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //traceCWrapper.provideDeviceMotion(tcimuEvent, Status, 0, RotationMode.Undetermined);
                    }
                };
                executorService.execute(provideDM);

            }
        };
        localBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getAppContext()).registerReceiver(
                sensorReceiver, new IntentFilter("imuCreated")
        );

        //register for locationBroadcast
        locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                TCLocationEvent tcLocationEvent = (TCLocationEvent) intent.getSerializableExtra("locationevent");
                Runnable provideLoc = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                traceCWrapper.provideLocation(tcLocationEvent);
                    }
                };
                executorService.execute(provideLoc);
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver( //Error Here <-----
                locationReceiver, new IntentFilter("locationCreated")
        );


        isRunning = true;

        //Start the Services

        AsyncTask as1 = new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                startUpdatingLocation();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

        AsyncTask as2 = new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                startUpdatingSensors();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
       
    }
    }
```

This is just one example i keep getting these errors all through the code which was copied in another example error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference
```

It seeems to especially be where is use

```
MyApplication.getAppContext......
```

MyApplication just returns as below:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }

}
```

How do i resolve these issues? The whole classes have been moved over it is not code taken from one class dumped into another. So not sure why context should have changed.

Comment: You cannot use Context in a static fashion it is considered a memory leak.

Comment: @TDIScott Do you have a suggestion, for someone who is new to android context on how to solve these issues?

Comment: I am sure there are better ways to do this and i will look at what @TDIScott mentioned thank you. However for the immediate i have fixed it i will add the answer just incase to helps anyone.

Comment: Try `this.getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

As i was using the MyApplication static context class in some places i needed to add this line to my Manifest file within the  tag

```
android:name="com.yourapp.app.yourapp.MyApplication"
```

and make sure the application class is placed in the top level main/java/com.yourapp.app.yourapp/

This worked for me and solved the issue throughout the App. I would pay attention to the comments made as this may well not be the best way to be using Context, however this solved my issue at the moment.